# How to get FormPreview from Django FormTools to work?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have tried to create a minimal working example of FormPreview of [Django FormTools](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/preview.html), but it did not work.

## forms.py

This is a very simple form.

```
from django.forms import CharField, Form, Textarea


class TextForm(Form):
    text = CharField(widget=Textarea)
```

## preview.py

This is with slight adjustments just copied from the documentation. It is of curse incomplete but I did not changed it because I did not even got to a preview page of any kind.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from formtools.preview import FormPreview


class TextFormPreview(FormPreview):
    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        # Add stuff later, once I get to a preview.
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

## urls.py

Here must be some mistake, but I don't know how it should be correct. Should I remove the first URL? How does FormPreview know what the correct view to use is?

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django import forms

from .forms import TextForm
from .preview import TextFormPreview

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.textform),
    url(r'^post/$', TextFormPreview(TextForm)),
]
```

## views.py

My simple views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import TextForm


def textform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            print(text)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TextForm

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'text.html', context)
```

## templates/text.html

And a simple template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Text</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.manual_recipients.errors }}
        {{ form.text }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## templates/base.html

base.html is just an empty file. If I go to ^post/$ it says it requires a base.html. Why? I do not know.

As said, I did all the steps from the documentation but it is obviously incomplete. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default template](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/blob/b518a9e59f76923ce8d226c61b9cb4eb3469d790/formtools/templates/formtools/preview.html) for `FormPreview` extends `base.html`. and includes a single block content.

In your base.html, you need to include {% block content %}{% endblock %}. A minimal template would be:

```
<html>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

See the docs on [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) for more info.

Comment: So I do not uses the views.py at all?

Comment: You have `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`, so you do need a url pattern and view for `r'^$`. However, that view does not handle the form, you could simply render a template that says "form processed".